# How to change the Y position of my parallax background in sprite kit Xcode?

Tags: ios, background, sprite-kit

This is my code for stars that move from left to right, I used it from a tutorial online:

```
    SKTexture* starsTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"stars"];
    starsTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    SKAction* movestarsSprite = [SKAction moveByX:-starsTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0.02 * starsTexture.size.width*2];
    SKAction* resetstarsSprite = [SKAction moveByX:starsTexture.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];
    SKAction* movestarsSpritesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[movestarsSprite, resetstarsSprite]]];

    for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width / ( starsTexture.size.width * 2 ); ++i ) {
        SKSpriteNode* starsSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:starsTexture];
        [starsSprite setScale:2.0];
        starsSprite.position = CGPointMake(i * starsSprite.size.width, starsSprite.size.height / 2);
          [starsSprite runAction:movestarsSpritesForever];
        [self addChild:starsSprite];
```

Im quite a beginner to coding, right now the stars show up repeating at the bottom of the screen and I want them to appear at the top like stars really would. What should I change to achieve that? Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinate system in SpriteKit has 0,0 bottom left of the screen so you need to increase the y coordinate of the position of the nodes to move them higher.

You currently have them set to:

`starsSprite.position = CGPointMake(i * starsSprite.size.width, starsSprite.size.height / 2);`

Try:

`starsSprite.position = CGPointMake(i * starsSprite.size.width, self.size.height - starsSprite.size.height / 2);`